# How can I tell which Google Chrome channel I'm running?

Tags: google-chrome, version

Is there a way from within Google Chrome to know whether I'm running the `stable`, `beta`, or `dev` channel?

I was experiencing problems with recent `dev` releases and decided to go back to `stable`. Now I want to make sure it worked.

In "About Google Chrome" is says

> 14.0.835.186 m

Does that `m` stand for `stable` perhaps?

By the way I'm on Windows but I assume there's a platform-independent way to check?

Comment: With my install of canary it says 16.0.891.0 canary

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try chrome://version/

Regular Chrome says:

```
Google Chrome   14.0.835.186 (Official Build 101821) m
OS  Windows
WebKit  535.1 (branches/chromium/835@94713)
JavaScript  V8 3.4.14.21
Flash   10,3,183,10
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.186 Safari/535.1
Command Line    "C:\Documents and Settings\geek\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --flag-switches-begin --enable-print-preview --flag-switches-end
Executable Path C:\Documents and Settings\geek\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Profile Path    C:\Documents and Settings\geek\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

Chrome Beta says:

```
Google Chrome   14.0.835.186 (Official Build 101821) beta-m
OS  Windows
WebKit  535.1 (branches/chromium/835@94713)
JavaScript  V8 3.4.14.21
Flash   10,3,183,10
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.186 Safari/535.1
Command Line    "C:\Documents and Settings\geek\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --flag-switches-begin --enable-print-preview --flag-switches-end
Executable Path C:\Documents and Settings\geek\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Profile Path    C:\Documents and Settings\geek\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

Dev says:

```
Google Chrome   14.0.835.186 (Official Build 101821) dev-m
OS  Windows
WebKit  535.1 (branches/chromium/835@94713)
JavaScript  V8 3.4.14.21
Flash   10,3,183,10
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.835.186 Safari/535.1
Command Line    "C:\Documents and Settings\geek\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --flag-switches-begin --enable-print-preview --flag-switches-end
Executable Path C:\Documents and Settings\geek\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Profile Path    C:\Documents and Settings\geek\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

Canary says:

```
Google Chrome   16.0.891.0 (Official Build 102650) canary
OS  Windows
WebKit  535.5 (@95897)
JavaScript  V8 3.6.4
Flash   11,0,1,148
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.891.0 Safari/535.5
Command Line    "C:\Documents and Settings\geek\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome SxS\Application\chrome.exe" --flag-switches-begin --enable-print-preview --flag-switches-end
Executable Path C:\Documents and Settings\geek\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome SxS\Application\chrome.exe
Profile Path    C:\Documents and Settings\geek\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome SxS\User Data\Default
```

Regular is m, Dev is dev-m and canary is canary

Comment: On my Mac, `chrome://version` doesn't work but `about://version` does. Other than that, +1.

Comment: @Jonik `chrome://version` works here. Chrome for Mac, latest beta version. What are you running?

Comment: about:version is what i tried. chrome changed it to chrome://version itself

Comment: @Jin, @Journeyman: Chrome 13.0.782.220. But after letting it update itself (to 14.0.835.186), it's now `chrome://version`! I stand corrected.

Comment: To me it shows `15.0.874.24 (Official Build 102155) beta-m`

Comment: Answer is out-of date? I don't see `m`, `beta-m`, etc. on mine.

Comment: this solution seems doesn't work anymore - `... (arm64)` is all I have

Comment: Well its been a decade since I posted this answer and I stopped using chrome since. I'll poke around and try to update this.

Answer (score 12):

According to the [official Chrome Release blog](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/search/label/Stable%20updates), your version is the latest stable version. I think if the version doesn't state either `beta` or `dev`, it's using the `stable` channel.

A little googling gives the following explanation of `m` flag.

```
// Return a human readable modifier for the version string, e.g. 
// the channel (dev, beta, stable). Returns true if this operation 
succeeded, 
// on success, channel contains one of "", "unknown", "dev" or 
"beta" (unless 
// it is a multi-install product, in which case it will return "m", 
// "unknown-m", "dev-m", or "beta-m"). 
static bool GetChromeChannel(bool system_install, std::wstring* 
channel);
```

[Source](http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-discuss/browse_thread/thread/f0201f87567aa456?pli=1)

> The "m" just means that you have multiple versions of Chrome installed in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application. You might have multiple versions of Chrome if you didn't download the latest version, but updated to it. The new version won't replace the old one, in case of installation failures. So in essence, when Chrome detects that you have more than one version of Chrome, it displays "m" after the version number in the [About Google Chrome] window.

[Source](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2011/08/stable-channel-update_22.html) (in comments)

Comment: Hmm I uninstalled my old Chrome first like Google's docs told me to do. Maybe the "m" is there because it detects some profile stuff for the other version?

Comment: @Jin, Are you saying "m" stands for "multiple"?

Answer (score 4):

It appears as if you are on stable channel.

You can just check the About Google Chrome as you already have and look for "beta" and "dev" version keywords. I'm running the latest beta channel version (on Windows 7) and my "About Google Chrome" window says "beta-m". An image of something similar to what you should see can be seen at [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21282/switch-between-release-channel-versions-of-google-chrome/)

Comment: Aha so it's just too lazy to say "stable" but if it says neither "beta" nor "dev" then it must be "stable" despite not saying so? (-:

Comment: Yes, it appears so. I just swapped from stable to beta channel, I went from no 'classifier' to having a beta classifier :-)

Answer (score 2):

if you installed it via adding it to `sources.apt` and doing `apt-get install google-chrome`, then:

doing:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep 'dl.google.com'
```

will print

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/ stable non-free
# this line is not output           ^ look here for the channel
```

Comment: Oh sorry I'm on Windows but I assumed there would be a platform-independent way to check so I didn't bother saying so in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I found most googlable answers over the net rather misleading. The letter "m" solely appears when your Google Update entries exist in your registry but your Google Chrome auto-update is disabled.

Answer (score -3):

If you go to chrome://chrome you'll get something like:

Version 30.0.1599.22 beta-m

As you can see, I'm running the beta version because it says 'beta'. The dev version would probably say something like 'dev-m' at the end. If you have neither, you're probably on the stable release.

Comment: You are just repeating previous answers